# XML and XSLT not working together

Tags: xml, codeigniter, xslt

I cannot get my XML to read my XSLT stylesheet. I am using a Framework - CodeIgniter - so that may or may not be part of the problem.

Here is my view code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/style.xsl") ?>" ?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">


<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url();?></loc> 
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<?php echo $file_list; ?>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url("release-calendar/upcoming-releases"); ?></loc> 
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url("release-calendar/currently-released"); ?></loc> 
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url("calendar/changes"); ?></loc> 
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

<?php echo $file_list_2; ?>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url("cookies"); ?></loc> 
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

<url>
    <loc><?php echo site_url("contact_us"); ?></loc> 
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

</urlset>
```

Here is my XSLT code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

  <html>
  <body>

    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="url">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="loc"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="priority"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

</body>
  </html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At the moment, the sitemap webpage does not even display in IE9 but does in Firefox. In Firefox it is actually rendering the XML (but just ignoring the styling).

The first 3 lines are in red text in the source code using Firefox if that means anything...

And the link to the stylesheet has to be correct because i use almost exactly the same link for my css stylesheet.

EDIT - Some extra information;

This is what my output is rendering;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/</loc> 
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/doc1.pdf</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/doc2.pdf</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/doc3.pdf</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/index.php/doc4.pdf</loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>

</urlset>
```

Seems fine to me..

Comment: Does the PHP output the correct MIME type for XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems around the root element of the XML

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

You have specified a default namespace here, meaning this element and all descendants (unless overridden with another namespace declaration) belong to that namespace. But there is no mention of the namespace at all in the XSLT, and so all your XPath expressions are looking for elements in NO namespace.

What you need to do in your XSLT is first declare your namespace, like so (the prefix 'sm' can be anything really, as long as uri matches the one in the XML)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Then, wherever you reference an element in an xpath expression, is should be prefixed with the namespace prefix. For example

```
    <xsl:for-each select="sm:url">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sm:loc"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sm:priority"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

The other issue is that you start off by matching the document node `<xsl:template match="/">`, but then within this template you do the xsl:for-each for the **url** element. But at this point, it is the **urlset** element that will be the immediate child element. Try changing the initial template match to this

```
<xsl:template match="/sm:urlset">
```

Then, your **xsl:for-each** should find something.

Of course, there may still be other problems. You need to ensure the XML you are outputing with PHP is well-formed, for a start.

Comment: I've added a snippet of my output if that helps. Seems ok to me.

Comment: I did mean "urlset", yes. I have corrected my answered accordingly. One thing is confusing though. In your input it has `<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">` and so all elements are in the namespace, but in your output it is `<urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`. A namespace prefix has appeared! But as this prefix is not used anywhere, all the elements are now in no namespace!

Comment: Actually, looking at your output, it seems to be lacking the `<?xml-stylesheet` processing instruction, so it looks like the CodeIgniter Framework could be at fault. I have no knowledge of that though, so I can't help there I am afraid.